# How to select Maximum and minimum date values and pass those as a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following entries

| CustomeID | TransDate | WorkID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2012-12-01 | 12 |
| 1 | 2012-12-03 | 45 |
| 1 | 2013-01-21 | 3 |
| 2 | 2012-12-23 | 11 |
| 3 | 2013-01-04 | 13 |
| 3 | 2013-12-24 | 16 |
| 4 | 2014-01-02 | 2 |

I am trying get the data between two dates and the required date values are minimum and maximum values of the column. I am able to get the desired output when I hard code the values.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE TransDate >= '2012-12-01' AND TransDate <= '2014-01-02'
```

I am aware the if I remove the where clause it will solve all the issues, But my actual query is much complex and has other conditions. The only way is to get maximum date values and minimum date value from the table and pass that reference to it.

I tried the below step but that does not work and throws the below error.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE TransDate >= '2012-12-01' AND TransDate <= MAX(TransDate)
```

Error

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Expected Output:

| CustomeID | TransDate | WorkID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2012-12-01 | 12 |
| 1 | 2012-12-03 | 45 |
| 1 | 2013-01-21 | 3 |
| 2 | 2012-12-23 | 11 |
| 3 | 2013-01-04 | 13 |
| 3 | 2013-12-24 | 16 |
| 4 | 2014-01-02 | 2 |

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: So you want the `MAX` value of `TransDate`, but not within the range of the filter? Use a subquery to get it? Use a CTE and a windowed aggregate to put the value in a column, and then filter outside of it based on `TransDate`?

Comment: Also, when is `TransDate   <= MAX(TransDate )` *not* going to be true, apart from when `TransDate`has the value `NULL`? A non-`NULL` value is **always** less than or equal to itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a scalar subquery to find the maximum date across the whole table:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE TransDate >= '2012-12-01' AND
      TransDate < (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, MAX(TransDate)) FROM dbo.MyTable);
```

Note that I am using a strict inequality (less than) in the `WHERE` clause against one day later than the max date.  This will include all days which fall on or earlier than the maximum date.

Comment: This feels somewhat pointless though, as the second clause will always be true with a non-`NULL` value. Even using `TransDate IS NOT NULL` would add no benefit, as those rows are already filtered in the first clause.

Comment: Yes, it feels pointless.  Will wait for feedback from the OP.

Comment: @Larnu I am mentioned in the question, the SQL  query is much complex and I wont be able to share those here. But this particular method works for me thanks.

Comment: Then at least give us something representative when you ask, @TarunSingh . It doesn't have to be your actual query, but it should be representive of it. Again, `{SomeDate} <= {SomeDate}` or `{SomeDate} < {SomeDate} + 1` will always be true. This will achieve nothing. It seems Tim has read your mind, and this has likely helped you achieve an answer to the real question you are asking (what ever that is), but the query above would act the same with or without the second clause in the `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare variables and then use them as given below:

```sql
DECLARE @minDate DATE = (SELECT MIN(TransDate) FROM Customer);
DECLARE @maxDate DATE = (SELECT MAX(TransDate) FROM Customer);

SELECT *  FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE   TransDate >= @minDate AND
    TransDate   <= @maxDate
```